# Changing Author Username Discord.py (AFK Commands)

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make AFK Commands with this code:

```
@bot.command(name="afk")
async def afk(ctx, username: str):
    username = ctx.message.author.name
    await ctx.author.edit(nick = f"[AFK]" + username)
    await ctx.send("Now You're in AFK Mode!")
```

But I having issue about these code, when I run the command it shows like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 789, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Stawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Stawa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 542, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: username is a required argument that is missing.
```

Comment: Did you write anything in username? Did you invoke the command as, for example, `!afk name` or anything similar? MissingRequiredArgument is usually raised if this space is not filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you used the command like this: `!afk` 
But you schould use it like that: `!afk someName`, because you said `username` is a required argument

Also you don't realy use the `username` argument, since you replace it with `ctx.auhtor.name` 
There are some ways to change this:

1. Just remove the `username` argument

```py
@bot.command(name="afk")
async def afk(ctx):   # <--- 
    username = ctx.author.name
```

2. Set a default with `= None` so `username` is not required anymore 
   You then can run this command with `!afk`

```
@bot.command(name="afk")
async def afk(ctx, username: str = None):   # <--- 
    username = ctx.author.name
```

2. Check if `username` is given, else use his normal name 
   The command can be used with `!afk` or `!afk someName`

```py
@bot.command(name="afk")
async def afk(ctx, username: str = None):   # <--- 
    if username is None:                    # <---
        username = ctx.author.name          # <---
    #   username =  ctx.author.display_name # <- this will use the old nick, if there is one, else the name
    await ctx.author.edit(nick = f"[AFK] {username}")
    await ctx.send("Now You're in AFK Mode!")
```